# The process cannot access the file ' ' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am trying to delete local copy(on the computer) of an image file once uploaded using file dialog. It throws The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Pictures\1220.bmp' because it is being used by another process.

```
private void _btnImportPhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //user clicked import/change photo, open file dialog to browse for photo
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
        fileDialog.Filter = ResourceFile.PhotoFileTypes;

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FilePath = fileDialog.FileName;
            FilePathCopy = fileDialog.FileName;
            string safeFilePath = fileDialog.SafeFileName;

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(FilePath);
            CurrentPhoto = bitmap;

            Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(FilePathCopy); //A copy to save when if delete local copy is chosen
            m_PhotoCopy = bitmap1;


             FileSystem.DeleteFile(FilePath);                   
            }
            _btnSave.IsEnabled = _btnCancel.IsEnabled = true;
        }
                }
```

Please let me know how to work around this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: find the other process and get it to release the lock on the file

Comment: Silently deleting files just because the user asks to have them opened? Even if you could get it to work, that would just make your users hire contract killers to get you.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: I didn't think you understood the process..Once a picture is uploaded to the application local copy on computer is deleted and user will be prompted if he/she wants to delete it..I didnot show all that code as it is unnecessary here... I would appreciate focusing on the solution to the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to dispose of the bitmap object try doing this. As this will dispose of the bitmap object as soon as it leaves the using context { }

```
using (Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(FilePathCopy))
{
  //do all bitmap stuff in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I see

```
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(FilePath);
  CurrentPhoto = bitmap;
```

Where `CurrentPhoto` I presume some global variable that you want hold.

This, instead throws and exception:

```
 FileSystem.DeleteFile(FilePath);
```

Cause image file at `FilePath` is actually `CurrentPhoto`. What you can do.

1) If use of `CurrentPhoto` has any sense inside this function, do what you want to do inside this function, and after dispose `CurrentPhoto` object, even in a way like @Bobby suggests (`using` block)

2) If you want to have it by the way, you can try to use Bitmap's [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx)
method like this:

```
CurrentPhoto = bitmap.Clone();
```

and after call your:

```
bitmap.Dispose();
FileSystem.DeleteFile(FilePath);
```

Should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

http://www.lockergnome.com/blade/2006/11/28/windows-error-message-error-deleting-file-or-folder/

It will allow you to delete files or folder.